# Access session in express node module

Tags: express

How can I access session variables from an external file in express.js?

I have two files: app.js:

```
/* app.js */
var express = require('express')
,   session = require('./session'); 

app.get('/', function( req, res ){
  req.session.status = 'edited in app.js';
});

app.get('/status', function( req, res ){
  session.getStatus(req, res);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And another session.js:

```
/* session.js */
exports.getStatus = function(req, res){
  console.log('the current status is' + req.session.status)
}
```

Both in the same directory.

As of right now, the console logs the session status as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've got express configured to use sessions:

```
  /* in app.js */
  app.configure(function(){
    ...
    app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
    app.use(express.session());
    ...
  });
```